# LinearLayout Horizontal inside LinearLayout Vertical

Tags: android, dynamic, nested, android-linearlayout

I am trying to put a linearlayout vertical inside the linear layout programmatically, but it seems that its not working, the buttons doesnt appear, but the text view appear...

Here is my code:
(this is for a dialog..)

```
LinearLayout titleLayout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

m_titleView = new TextView(m_context);
m_titleView.setText(title);


LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

Button backward = new Button(m_context);
backward.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
backward.setText("Backwards");

Button newDirButton = new Button(m_context);
newDirButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
newDirButton.setText("New folder");

horizontalLayout.addView(backward);
horizontalLayout.addView(newDirButton);
titleLayout.addView(m_titleView);
titleLayout.addView(horizontalLayout);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting LayoutParams on `horizontalLayout`.

Anyway, I'd suggest moving to xml world, as this code is not maintainable.

**Edit:**

Answer found by the author:

```
titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

should be:

```
horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was a misstype at the sixth line, it should be horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); not titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);   lol..

Comment: That only shows how maintainable this code was ;) You may want to move your comment to an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yes you are right, no, I will accept yours for your effort ;)